# How to make a javascript link behave like a html link?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to use Javascript for a link (at least I think so) in my openlayers map:

```
map.on("click", e => {
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, (feature) => {
        window.location.href = "/s/" + feature.getId();
        return true; // stop after first feature
    });
});
```

This works fine, but lacks some things:

- There is no indication where the link is going to take me when hovering it.
- Command-click does not open it in a new tab.

I thought about listening to hover and checking if *command* is pressed, but this seems error prone and only works for known system configurations.

Is there a way to make a javascript link work just like a HTML link?

Comment: Might be an over simplistic approach - but what about generating actual `<a>` tags dynamically?

Comment: Tracking the cursor and positioning an invisible `<a>` under it you mean? I might actually try that.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap your map with **< a >** tag and update **href** accordingly, that would:

- give browser hint to propagate to user,
- and could solve your separate tab/window issue.

you can also look at **window.open**, although it might be registered as 'popup' and blocked.